# Elixir System.cmd isn't working

Tags: elixir

```
System.cmd "echo", ["hello"]
```

is not working in windows. I am trying to run this in `iex`. This is the error I am getting:

> (ErlangError) Erlang error: :enoent
>       (elixir) lib/system.ex:605: `System.cmd("echo", ["hello"], [])`

Comment: Please stop blaming Elixir and blame your “operating” system. There are likely issues with `echo` command in Windows. Try `System.cmd("dir", [], [])`.

Comment: No luck. Same error. I am not blaming Elixir. I am just curious why isn't it running in windows

Comment: Please share at least what version of elixir do you use so that we could see the line producing error in the elixir code.

Comment: I am using Elixir 1.5.1 in windows 10. I am able to run perl script using System.cmd of elixir but issues are with dos commands. In linux system System.cmd "ls", [] works fine.

Comment: Ah. Of course. Last time I have Windows seen was 1999, but I doubt anything has changed since then: you must specify the full command name, namely `echo.exe`: `System.cmd "echo.exe", ["hello"], []`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work as expected:

`System.cmd("cmd.exe",["/c","echo","hello"])`

Note that you need to invoke `cmd.exe` because `echo` is an internal command.  Also you need to specify the `/c` argument to the command because otherwise the echo will never terminate and return.

Also since `dir` is an internal command that would look something like this:

`System.cmd("cmd.exe",["/c","dir","*.exe"])`

By the way, this has nothing to do with the Phoenix Framework.